# Comparison between two times wrong

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```
function get_time(){
    //Input first have Time
    var st = parseInt($(".el:first").attr("num"));

    //Input secound Have Time
    var end = parseInt($(".el:last").attr("num"));

    //Get Date 
    var d = new Date();

    // Get Hours And Minutes
    var h = ("0" + (d.getHours())).slice(-2); 
    var m = ("0" + (d.getMinutes())).slice(-2);

    //Convert Hours And Minutes To Number To Easy Comparison And Save It To Var t
    var t = h + '' + m;

    //Get ALL Times From First Input To Last Input 
    while(st <=end){
        //Time One
        var from = $('.from'+st).val().replace(':','');

        //Time Two
        var to = $('.to'+st).val().replace(':','');

        //if t > time1 And  < time2 
        if (t>= from && t<to){
            alert(true);
        } else {
            alert(false);
        }

        st++;
    }
}
```

Every thing Working But I have 1 Problem
Ex: I have

```
t = 5:30 AM
From = 2:30
To = 6:30
```

true 
But

```
t = 5:30 AM
From = 3:30
To  = 2:30 (New Day)
```

False

This is my problem And I Can`t  set Date Ex day or Mounth Or Year Becouse I run this code every day

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting all the dates/times into either a Date object for comparison or into unix time. Comparing strings together is 1. not very straight forward. 2. is slower than comparing numbers. It looks like the confusion lies in your comparison not taking into consideration am and pm. You could keep your comparison if you converted all the numbers to military time (23:30 === 11:30 pm) or you could load the times from your "st" and "end" variables into a date object to compare with the current date.

```js
function getTime(){
  var st = $(".el:first").attr("num"),
    end = $(".el:last").attr("num"),
    now = new Date();
    
    //custom function to parse elements into Dates
    var startDate = convertToDate(st);
    var endDate = convertToDate(end);
    
    if(startDate <= now && now < endDate){
      alert(true);
    }else{
      alert(false);
    }

}

function convertToDate(element){
    //do code here to create Date object and then return it
}
```